# iOS app Crashing on line Databse().reference() of Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This issue started suddenly. It had been working fine for the last couple of days authenticating with Facebook accounts. Today I tried implementing the `Auth.auth().createUser(email: ... password:... completion:...)` and suddenly my app started crashing right after authentication in function `func completeSignIn(id:..., userData:...)` at `DataService.ds.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: usr.uid, userData: ["provider": "Email"])`, it crashes in the Firebase Singleton at the line `Database().reference()`. I'm very lost. I checked out a branch where it used to work, but now it doesn't work either, so I created a new app in Firebase, but I'm getting the same issue. I've seen this question in a couple of places, but no answer. It's throwing the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
```

but I've checked the id and the dictionary that I'm passing and the values are there. Any help is appreciated.

Create Account code:

```
@IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let pwd = pwdField.text{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pwd, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to Authenticate E-mail with Firebase - Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }else{
                print("Successfully Authenticated E-mail with Firebase")
                if let usr = user {
                    let keychainResult = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(usr.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                    print("Data saved to Keychain: \(keychainResult)")
                    DataService.ds.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: usr.uid, userData: ["provider": "Email"])
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

FBLogin and Email Auth:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Start Login Process")
    let fbLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    print("Set Read Permissions")
    //TODO: add Read Permissions
    fbLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","user_location"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Unable to provide Authentication with Facebook - \(String(describing: error))")
        }else if result?.isCancelled == true{
            print("User Cancelled FB Authentication")
        }else {
            print("User Successfully Logged In")
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            self.firebaseAuth(credential)
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func emailLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Unable to Authenticate Firebase - \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                print("Succesfully authenticated with Firebase")
                if let user = user{
                    let userData = ["provider": "email"]
                    self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userData: userData)
                }
            }

        })
    }
}


func firebaseAuth(_ credential: AuthCredential){
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("Succesfully authenticated with Firebase")
            if let user = user{
                let userData = ["provider": credential.provider]
                self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userData: userData)
            }
        } else{
            print("Unable to Authenticate Firebase - \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    })
}


func completeSignIn(id: String, userData: Dictionary<String, String>){
    DataService.ds.createFirebaseDBUser(uid: id, userData: userData)
    let keychainResult = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(id, forKey: KEY_UID)
    print("Data saved to Keychain: \(keychainResult)")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: nil)
}
```

Firebase Singleton class DataService:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

let DB_BASE = Database().reference()

class DataService {

static let ds = DataService()

private(set) var REF_BASE = DB_BASE
private(set) var REF_PROMOS = DB_BASE.child("promos")
private(set) var REF_NEGOCIOS = DB_BASE.child("negocios")
private(set) var REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")

func createFirebaseDBUser(uid: String, userData: Dictionary<String, String>){
    REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
}

}
```

Comment: It should be `Database.database().reference()`

Comment: @creeperspeak you are the man! I have no idea how that got deleted, but it's working now!

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is having a fresh set of eyes on it.  Glad to help!

Comment: would you mind writing that as the answer? so I can approve you and upvote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get a reference to your existing database rather than trying to initialize a new one.  Change `Database().reference()` to `Database.database().reference()`.